# How could EF Code First Migrations ever be considered "good" coding practice?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, database-design, architecture, ef-code-first

In an introduction to Entity Framework tutorial I am viewing there is some time spent describing and demonstrating creating and changing database tables using Code First Migrations. In Code First Migrations, custom classes that have been added to a DbContext sub-class are used to create the corresponding database tables for the first time. Then we are shown how a change to one of those classes such as an addition of a new property could be pushed to the database table. Here is my current thinking on this:

All this ability to define classes, create db tables from them, make changes, push changes to the db seems targeted at developers who don't know databases and database syntax. I would argue that if a developer doesn't know database design and syntax well enough to do this stuff in the native environment and syntax of the target database server he shouldn't be doing it at all; especially not in an environment that abstracts the details. To say it another way, it is much easier and clearer to just use the native db tools and techniques to create the database objects.

My question is, why would a professional developer or a development shop ever use these techniques for any form of database object creation or maintenance?

I should probably add that I am not asking this question to indict those that are using this. I ask the question because if I am missing something I want to know what it is.

Comment: I imagine companies running enterprise level systems may prefer to have a DBA on hand to do database migrations, while a single developer writing a web service for an app without budget for a DBA may appreciate the simplicity of migrations. To each their own I'd say.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no requirement to use migrations with Code First. You could use a database project or one of the methods Chris mentions here: http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/#at_pco=smlwn-1.0&at_si=54ad5c7b61c48943&at_ab=per-12&at_pos=0&at_tot=1

Your question seems more about the Code First workflow of which there are many debate points. Putting the objects before the relational database is not something a lot of veteran developers are comfortable with.

> “seems targeted at developers who don't know databases and database
>   syntax”

– EF’s Wikipedia entry says it nicely: “The Entity Framework enables developers to work with data in the form of domain-specific objects and properties, such as customers and customer addresses, without having to concern themselves with the underlying database tables and columns where this data is stored. With the Entity Framework, developers can work at a higher level of abstraction when they deal with data, and can create and maintain data-oriented applications with less code than in traditional applications.”

> “why would a professional developer or a development shop ever use
>   these techniques for any form of database object creation or
>   maintenance?”

– As a professional developer, you still need to know the tenants of OOD (containment, composition, etc.) and apply SOLID principles. 
With either workflow you are still going to butt heads with the [impedance mismatch.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch)

BTW, I work in a shop with very strict DBAs. Our team still uses EF with migrations but we use the nice script generation techniques to supply them with scripts to update the schema. Is it the right tool for every shop or project? No. In fact we have been looking into Dapper as a more lite weight layer.